# Difference between dashed line area and feathering radius in darktable

Tags: darktable, selection

In darktable, when you make a selection, e.g. to increase the exposure of a specific area, there is the selection outline, and a dotted exterior line.  The distance between the main selection and that exterior border can be changed.  There is also an adjustment for feathering on the module.  What exactly does the dotted line represent, and how is that different from feathering?  Both seem to have a similar affect, to my untrained eye.

For example, if the dotted area is close in to the solid selection, and I set the feathering to 200px, how is that different from making the dotted border farther away from the solid selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case (solid line vs dotted line) a simple gradient is used between the lines, independent of the content of the image.

For example this selection

[image]

leads to the this mask

[image]

The "feathering" is something more involved.  From the [documentation](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.0/en/darkroom/masking-and-blending/masks/refinement-controls/):

> Mask feathering smooths a drawn or parametric mask such that the mask’s edges automatically align with the edges of features in the image.

Example enabling feathering on the above mask:

[image]

---

The feathering can be very useful to more precisely separate different areas in the image with a mask.  To give a more realistic use-case:  Assume I want to mask the tree.  One option would be to use a rough drawn mask (without gradient) which goes along the edges of the tree but does not need to match exactly.  Then I increase feathering, to make the mask follow more accurately the edges of the tree:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, especially with the mask displayed.  With regard to the dotted line, is the module affect more or less guaranteed NOT to extend past the dotted line?  For feathering, where does the extent of the feathering start?  I had thought the solid line, but it appears to work on both sides of the line, potentially effectively moving the line somewhat inward.  Is the extent of feathering split evenly on both sides of the solid line?  Or is it the full amount on both the outside and inside?

Comment: I think for the gradient case, the mask is fully opaque within the solid line, then fades out and does indeed not extend beyond the dotted line.  The feathering is independent of how you drew the mask (it also works for parametric masks, for example), so it doesn't know about these lines. As it is trying to find edges, the amount and direction of its effect depends on the content of the image.

Comment: I thought the parametric was confined within the drawn, which is what I usually want.  As I have only used it to exclude areas when combining the two, it's hard to tell. (As in this [eyes](https://www.reddit.com/r/DarkTable/comments/fuco4y/help_hole_in_masks/) example)

Comment: This is indeed the default case when using a "drawn & parametric mask" (it can be changed with the "combine masks" setting, though).  The feathering, however, is not part of the "parametric mask" but of the "mask refinement" settings, which are applied in the end on the already combined mask.